# LINQ как пройтись по всем столбам таблицы?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, linq, aggregate

В общем,есть у меня БД. Все ее сущности записаны в этом классе

```
[Table(Name = "TestDate")]
public class TestDate
{


    [Column(Name = "START_PAGE")]
    public string start_page { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "USERR")]
    public Int64 user { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "TS")]
    public string ts { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DEPTH")]
    public string depth { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DURATION")]
    public string duration { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "TRANSMIT")]

    public string transmit { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "TYPE")]

    public string type { get; set; }

}
```

Далее создаю класс,чтобы посчитать сумму,среднее армефметическое и т.д. для каждого типа (type).
Но у меня получилось только пройтись по колонке user и всё посчитать.

```
 static class AggregateFunc


{
  static string connectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Testovoe;Integrated Security=True";

    public static void Agg()
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext(connectionString);

        Table<TestDate> tests = db.GetTable<TestDate>();
        var prod = (from p in tests select p.type).ToList().Distinct();

            foreach (string i in prod)
            {

                var query = db.GetTable<TestDate>().Where(u => u.type == i).Count();
                var value = (from p in tests where p.type == i select p.user).Sum();
                var max = (from p in tests where p.type == i select p.user).Max();
                var min = (from p in tests where p.type == i select p.user).Min();
                var avg = (from p in tests where p.type == i select p.user).Average();
                Console.WriteLine("Type " + i + " " + query + " " + "Sum " + value + " Max " + max + " Min " + min + " Avg " + avg);

        }


       db.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM TestDate");
       db.SubmitChanges();
       Console.ReadKey();



    }


}
```

Дело в том,что мне надо пройтись по **ВСЕМ** столбам этой таблицы и посчитать sum,avg,min,max для каждого столбца.

Как лучше поступить в этой ситуации?

*Извиняюсь за корявый код,только учусь.*

Схема бд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше в эту ситуации пересмотреть схему бд

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавила схемку (только там ничего примечательного,одинокая табличка)

Comment: может вам лучше высчитывать это, когда вы вытягиваете данные с БД? еще вариант - рефлексия (позволит вытащить поля с модели и пройтись по ним)...ну и все таки присмотритесь к первому коменту